# DOTENV enviroment parameter getting UNDEFINED

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 in which I want to get dote ENV environment variables.

but when console log getting **UNDEFINED**

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()

console.log(process.env.PORT)

const app = express();

//middlewares


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(
        "<h1> Welcome to my aapp</h1>"
    );
})
//port


  app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port number 8000`)
})
```

`//OUTPUT is UNDEFINED`

Comment: in DOTENV file I have PORT=8000

Comment: Could you please try to read it in Node v20? Node V20 comes with inbuilt env reading feature and we don't want to install dotenv seperately. After upgrading the node version, run you app like this:
```node --env-file=config.env index.js```

You can replace index.js with your main file name

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed your dotenv?
Try running this to see if that helps.

```
npm i dotenv
```

Comment: I have installed dotenv,,,its version 6.13.1

Comment: But installation is not a problem or error, but I want to get environment parameter PORT number in console.?????                                                                                                              IF any solution of this problem ??? Kindly mention what have to change in code